# Android - Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-package-managers

I'm having some problems trying to install APKs in a specific device. I have lots of devices and it hadn't happened so far (all of them, Radxa Rock Pro).

When I run `pm install myApp` I get

```
root@radxaPro:/ # pm install /sdcard/myApp.apk
pkg: /sdcard/myApp.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
```

Logcat output:

```
06-02 13:02:33.032 I/AndroidRuntime( 4469): JNI options: '-Xjniopts:warnonly'
06-02 13:02:33.042 D/dalvikvm( 4469): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-02 13:02:33.042 D/dalvikvm( 4469): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-02 13:02:33.052 D/dalvikvm( 4469): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-02 13:02:33.052 D/dalvikvm( 4469): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-02 13:02:33.052 D/dalvikvm( 4469): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
06-02 13:02:33.082 D/dalvikvm( 4469): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
06-02 13:02:33.232 E/memtrack( 4469): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-02 13:02:33.232 E/android.os.Debug( 4469): failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-02 13:02:33.282 D/AndroidRuntime( 4469): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
06-02 13:02:33.292 W/ActivityManager( 474): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService } U=0: not found
06-02 13:02:33.292 E/PackageManager( 474): Failed to bind to media container service
```

I think the most important line is `Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService } U=0: not found` because a successful installation shows this (another device):

```
06-02 13:04:35.747: I/AndroidRuntime(1005): JNI options: '-Xjniopts:warnonly'
06-02 13:04:35.757: D/dalvikvm(1005): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-02 13:04:35.767: D/dalvikvm(1005): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
06-02 13:04:35.767: D/dalvikvm(1005): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-02 13:04:35.767: D/dalvikvm(1005): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
06-02 13:04:35.767: D/dalvikvm(1005): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
06-02 13:04:35.797: D/dalvikvm(1005): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
06-02 13:04:35.927: E/memtrack(1005): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-02 13:04:35.927: E/android.os.Debug(1005): failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-02 13:04:35.977: D/AndroidRuntime(1005): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
06-02 13:04:35.987: I/ActivityManager(478): Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=1016 uid=10001 gids={50001, 1028, 1015, 1023, 2001, 1035}
```

The *DefaultContainerService.apk* is located in `/system/priv-app/` but I have been able to check that it is not actually installed in that device. If I try to install it, I get the same error.

Does anyone have an idea? Is the Android system corrupt?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. I have the same problem since I uninstalled DefaultContainerService.apk by mistake, and now I can't install it. Is there any solution other than "pm"? Thanks.